# MongoDB: Aggregate function returns the output of strings as a single array. How can they be converted into individual arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**The aggregate function i have used :-**

```
User.aggregate([
 {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "DescriptionArray": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$services.description",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": {
          "$concatArrays": [
            "$$this",
            "$$value"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "PicArray": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$services.pic",
        "initialValue": [],
        "in": {
          "$concatArrays": [
            "$$this",
            "$$value"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
   }
}
])
```

**Gives me the output in the following manner :-**

```
[ { DescriptionArray:
 [ 'Des1',
   'Des2',
   'Des3',
   'Des4' ],
PicArray:
 [ 'Pic1.jpeg',
   'Pic2.jpeg',
   'Pic3.jpeg',
   'Pic4.jpeg' ] },
{ DescriptionArray:
 [ 'Des5',
   'Des6' ],
PicArray: [ 'Pic5.jpeg', 'Pic6.jpeg' ] } ]
```

**But i want output to be of the format where each element of it treated as an individual array rather than as that of single array consisting of many elements in the following manner:-**

```
 [
  { DescriptionArray: [ 'Des1' ],
   PicArray: [ 'Pic1.jpeg' ],
 },
 { DescriptionArray: [ 'Des2' ],
  PicArray: [ 'Pic2.jpeg' ],
 },
{ DescriptionArray: [ 'Des3' ],
  PicArray: [ 'Pic3.jpeg' ],
 },
{ DescriptionArray: [ 'Des4' ],
  PicArray: [ 'Pic4.jpeg' ],
 },
{ DescriptionArray: [ 'Des5' ],
  PicArray: [ 'Pic5.jpeg' ],
 },
{ DescriptionArray: [ 'Des6' ],
  PicArray: [ 'Pic6.jpeg' ],
 }
]
```

> What can be done inorder to get the output in the above manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query in 3.4 and more.

```
User.aggregate([
  {"$project":{
    "array":{
      "$map":{
        "input":{"$range":[0,{"$size":"$services.description"}]},
        "as":"ix",
        "in":{
         "DescriptionArray":{"$arrayElemAt":["$services.description","$$ix"]},
         "PicArray":{"$arrayElemAt":["$services.pic","$$ix"]}}
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$array"},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$array"}}
])
```